# Count items, rows, users, etc in Katalon Studio

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I am having some problem with Katalon Studio.

Can I somehow count items on the page by class or something?

I can do it with JavaScript but I don't know how to do it with
groovy language in Katalon studio.

`document.getElementsByClassName("").length`

I'm trying to convert this JavaScript code into groovy but nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the same method of `size()` like done in Table:

See [documentation](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/handle_web_tables.html#example-1you-want-to-get-a-text-from-a-web-table-and-verify-it).

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By as By

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver as WebDriver

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement as WebElement

WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
'To locate table'
WebElement Table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody"))
'To locate rows of table it will Capture all the rows available in the table'
List<WebElement> rows_table = Table.findElements(By.tagName('tr'))
'To calculate no of rows In table'
int rows_count = rows_table.size()
println('No. of rows: ' + rows_count)
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Hey, it run successfully but i dont get it where did it print the number of rows ? :D

Comment: it is printed to the console... :)

Comment: Thank you so much !! and sorry for such a dumb question ! can i ask you one more question about Katalon ?

Comment: glad to help! feel free to ask! this is SO that's what we are here for!

Comment: Is there any way to compare now that result with the data from database ?

Comment: yes! you get the number of items from the DB see here: https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/connect_db_gui_testing.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185726/discussion-between-brithwulf-and-moshe-slavin).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use WebUiBuiltInKeywords to findWebElements as specified in the following URL. It will return a list of elements matching the locator.

```
static List<WebElement> findWebElements(TestObject to, int timeOut)
// Internal method to find web elements by test object
```

Examples

```
def elements = WebUiBuiltInKeywords.findWebElements(to, 5)
println elements.size()
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this

```
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
def eleCount = driver.findElements(By.className("your-class")).size()
println eleCount //prints out the number of the elements with "your-class" class
```

Comment: Hello, I did that but it says an error : "unexpected token: println @ line42, column1.

Comment: Sorry, I was missing an ")". Please, check the edited answer.